# Latency when recording and playing audio at the same time on bluetooth headset

Tags: android, performance, audio, bluetooth, headset

I am recording and reproducing audio at the same time. When I used headphones, the latency is very small (I almost do not peceive there is a delay - lets say less than 100ms). However, when I use bluetooth headphones the latency increases significantly (lets say 300ms) and I perceive the recoding is playing with a greater delay. Here is how I configure the AudioTrack and AudioRecorder

```
    int encoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
    private Thread recordingThread = null;
    private AudioRecord recorder = null;
    private AudioTrack track = null;
    private AudioManager am = null;
    private int sampleRate = 8000;
    int minSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, encoding); 
    private int bufferSize = minSize;

///////////////////

        track = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL,
                sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO,
                encoding, minSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        // Audio record object
        recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION, sampleRate,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, encoding,
                bufferSize);
```

Recording and playing runs on a thread

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);
            buffer = new byte[minSize];
            // Playback received audio
            track.play();

            recorder.startRecording();

            while (true) {
                recorder.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize,  AudioRecord.READ_BLOCKING);
                track.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length, AudioTrack.WRITE_BLOCKING);
            }

        }
```

I want to decrease the latency when recording and playing on the bluetooth headset. Do you think that Using openSL ES would help? Suggestions please

Thanks

Comment: Probably unavoidable. There's BT buffers that are in use, here, and they probably have a fixed size which is manufactured into the hardware.

Comment: I cant feel such delay when I make a regular call, and both phones are connected to bluetooth headsets.